# What are the 'best' XNA developed games for PC?

Tags: c#, xna

I've had a quick google, but can't find anything obvious that answers the question. What are the best games developed using XNA for PC? Any flagship games, original games.. etc?

Obviously 'best' is pretty subjective, but I'm sure they'll be a common consensus on some of the good ones.

(I don't own an XBox (if that matters...))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft holds an annual [Dream-Build-Play](http://www.dreambuildplay.com) contest. The 2009 winner, Dust: An Elysian Tail ([trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tR7vE6l1MN0)) was pretty impressive!

Comment: That game looks immense! and DBP contest looks like a great link. Thanks